# When is a hypersurface rationally connected?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

A projective variety $X$ is said to be "rationally connected" if any two points on it can be connected by a map $\mathbb P^1 \to X$.

Let $X$ be a smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb P^n_k$ defined by a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field.  It is mentioned in many places that $X$ is rationally connected if and only if $d < n$.  However, I haven't been able to write a proof in detail.

Here's what I know: If the anticanonical bundle of $X$ is ample, then a result of Kollar-Miyaoka-Mori says that $X$ is rationally connected.  The anticanonical bundle of $X$ is ample if and only if $d<n$.  I don't know how to show that rational connectedness implies the condition $d<n$.

How does one complete the proof?  Is there a simpler argument to prove this?

Comment: I think I can treat a very easy case, which is the case $n = 2$. Then it follows from the genus-degree formula and the Riemann-Hurwitz formula that a smooth degree d curve in the plane is rationally connected iff $d \leq 2$ (smooth degree two curves are also rational, so something is funny about your statement). Or maybe I am not understanding your condition?

Comment: @AreaMan: The condition is $d<n$.

Comment: What is the issue with a smooth deg 2 curve in the plane? D and n are both 2. It's rational, so if it's not rationally connected, then what do you mean by rationally connected? (Your definition is a little vague.) Why isn't this curve a counterexample? I don't understand.

Comment: AreaMan is correct. The right condition is $d<n+1$

Answer (score 2):

One can use the following:

A projective variety $X$ is rationally connected if and only if there exists a rational curve $f:\mathbb{P}^{1}\to X$ such that $f^{*}T_{X}$ is ample.

Now suppose that $X\subset \mathbb{P}^{n}$ is a smooth hypersurface of degree $d>n$. Then the canonical divisor $K_{X}$ is either ample or trivial. Let $f:\mathbb{P}^{1}\to X$ be a rational curve. Calculating intersection numbers we get:

$K_{X}.f_{*}\mathbb{P}^{1}=c_{1}(f^{*}K_{X})=-c_{1}(f^{*}T_{X})=-\sum a_{i}$

where $f^{*}T_{X}\cong \bigoplus_{i} \mathcal{O}_{P^{1}}(a_{i})$. But since $K_{X}$ is either ample or trivial, $K_{X}.f_{*}\mathbb{P}^{1}$ cannot be negative, so $f^{*}T_{X}$ cannot be ample.